# How to add Icon for application in itunes?

Tags: ios, itunes

I have signed application with adhoc distribution profile.
i can install the application to registered devices.the only minor problem is in tunes the application is not seen with icon that i have given to application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon used in iTunes is defined by the "iTunesArtwork" file, which should be a 512x512 PNG file without the png extension (the icon is 57x57 -- 114x114 for Retina)

See [here in Apple's doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW7) for more details.